# Previously faulting unaligned calls now working?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64

I'm not sure if I'm delusional, but I'm **near certain** calls used to fail on System V Linux x86_64 if they weren't aligned upon entry (i.e. you'd purposely disalign the stack before a `call` so it's aligned upon entry).

For example (this now works):

```
.data
str: .asciz "string literal"

.text
.globl main
main:
    lea str(%rip), %rdi
    call puts@plt
    xor %eax, %eax
    ret
```

I'm near certain this used to fail, can someone explain if I am: delusional (i.e. this has always worked), misunderstanding the semantics of stack alignment, unaware of (somewhat recent?) changes in something, somewhere?

Previously I'd always purposely disaligned using a `push`(as per the common prologue) or simply `sub $8, %rsp`, but now code I write without doing that seems to work just fine?

Is this a nuance or is this behaviour now acceptable?

Comment: It’s always wrong; but that doesn’t mean it always fails. Some functions always fail, some don’t, and some are data dependent. (I believe scanf is one that always fails, and printf is data dependent, if I remember correctly. It doesn’t surprise me that puts doesn’t fail.)

Comment: @prl I suspected there was some nuance involved. I thought the fault was triggered by something far more general than the actual target implementation? I sort of convinced myself there was some embedded semantics of x86_64 processors to signal a fault upon entry to `call` locations of the stack pointer wasn't 16 bytes aligned?

Comment: The processor generates a fault when certain SSE instructions are used with an unaligned address. If the called function doesn’t use such an instruction with a location on the stack, it won’t fault.

Comment: The call itself won’t ever fault, nor will most types of instructions.

Comment: Oh, right, so it's still just best practice to write code that purposely disaligns the stack before `call`s I assume, since we can't be certain of the implementation of dynamically-linked calls. I appreciate the swift answer, I was doubting things before asking. Cheers, feel free to summarise those comments as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to clear up something in your question and your last comment--the stack is *unaligned* on entry to a function, and you need to *align* it before making a call.

Comment: *you'd purposely disalign the stack before a call so it's aligned upon entry.*  You have it exactly backwards.  You align the stack *before* `call`, so any stack args start at a 16-byte boundary.  And so on function entry, you have 16B - 8 alignment, i.e. exactly 8 bytes away from 16B alignment.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks for the clarification, both of you. I dunno where I gathered that false understanding, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not delusional. The x86-64 SysV ABI requires that the stack be aligned to 16 before calling an external function, implying that the stack pointer value mod 16 is 8 on entry to a function, and that it must be adjusted by an odd multiple of 8 to realign it prior to calling another function. However, this is not strictly enforced. The call itself won't ever fault, nor will most types of instructions used to access the stack. It only causes a fault if the called function accesses a value on the stack using an instruction that requires alignment, such as certain SSE instructions (including SSE extensions and AVX).

The implementations of some library functions always perform such an access, so they will always fault on an unaligned stack. Some other library functions may perform such accesses to the stack depending on the data they are passed, and some don't ever use such accesses, and will not fault regardless of stack alignment. However, it is unwise to rely on any of this, since the implementations can change. Always align your stack before making a call.

Comment: The ABI actually says 16 or 32-bytes or 64-bytes but that is dependent on the parameters passed.

Comment: IIRC, 32 or 64-byte alignment before the call is only required when passing a `__m256i` or `__m512i` on the stack, instead of in a YMM or ZMM reg.  It's very much a corner case of the ABI.  (Possibly could also happen if passing an `alignas(64)` large struct by value, which would also go on the stack.)  So not something you generally have to worry about.